# Benthos - How do you reference keywords from one processor to another processor in the same pipeline?

Tags: pipeline, benthos

I am new to Benthos and trying to learn how it works. I am trying to input a JSON file with some key:value pairs, add a new field and POST that new field to get a response.

```
pipeline:
  processors:
    - mapping: |
      root.id = this.id
      root.submitName = "testingAcc"
      root.cost = this.cost
            
      let idLen = root.id.length()
      let nameLen = root.submitName.length()
      root.send = $idLen + root.id + $nameLen + root.submitName + this.cost
                  
    - branch:
      request_map: |
        root = this.send
      processors:
        - http:
          url: "<http link>"
          verb: POST
      result_map: |
        root.response = this.content().string()
```

---

Example

Input = {"id": "1", "cost": "500"}
Mapping = {"id": "1", "submitName": "testingAcc", "cost": "500", "send": "1110testingAcc500"}

Value that sends via POST = 1110testingAcc500

Branch = {"id": "1", "submitName": "testingAcc", "cost": "500", "send": "1110testingAcc500", "response": "OK"}

---

However, when I run this I get an error saying that the request_map line (`root = this.send`) did not find the expected key. I thourght this would work as I mapped the send value so it could be referenced in the branch processor. I have tried different ways to call the keyword (like `root = this.send`, `root = root.send`, etc.) but all the same error.

Hopefully I explained this well. I tried googling the error and reading documentation but couldn't find an answer or any examples to help me understand. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be seeing this error: `Branch error: request mapping failed: failed assignment (line 1): unable to reference message as structured (with 'this.send'): parse as json: invalid character 'b' looking for beginning of value`. The reason is because the `this` keyword mandates that the current in-flight message is in JSON format (if it was in JSON format, but the key didn't exist, you'd get a null value in `root`).

In your case, I think the `mapping` processor is failing and then the in-flight message gets passed unchanged to the next processor in the pipeline (the `branch` processor). You should first ensure that your message is valid JSON by using a `log` processor (if it's not, you can use the `content()` function in a `mapping` processor to extract the message data and parse it somehow) and then you need to fix the data type issues in your `mapping` processor. Bloblang does not allow implicit conversions from integer to string, so you'll need to use `$idLen.string()` and `$nameLen.string()` (and maybe `this.cost.string()` if `cost` happens to be numeric). Try using `benthos blobl server` to prototype your bloblang mappings.

Answer (score 0):

As Mihai pointed out, the issue was Here is a working version of your config:

```
input:
  generate:
    mapping: 'root = {"id": "1", "cost": "500"}'
pipeline:
  processors:
    - mapping: "root.id = this.id\nroot.submitName = \"testingAcc\"\nroot.cost = this.cost\n      \nlet idLen = root.id.length()\nlet nameLen = root.submitName.length()\nroot.send = $idLen.string() + root.id + $nameLen.string() + root.submitName + this.cost\n          \n"
    - branch:
        request_map: |
          root = this.send
        processors:
          - http:
              url: https://a.com
              verb: POST
        result_map: |-
          root.response = content().string()
output:
  stdout: {}
```